# How to specify Docker private registry credentials in Docker configuration File?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-registry

I am creating Docker container of nodejs application. Below is the sample of my Docker configuration file

```
FROM node:6.11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
npm install
copy . /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

This will download the node image from Docker hub and then it will create Docker image as per the configuration.

For security reasons I don't want to download nodejs image from Docker hub, Instead I want to use my private repository to download nodejs image.

As I have setup private repository I am not sure how to specify registry credentials in DockerFile.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, docker pulls all images from Dockerhub. If you want to pull an image from another registry, you have to prefix the image name with the registry URL. Check the [official docker pull documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry).

In your case, you have 2 options:

The first is to specify explicitly the registry inside the Dockerfile as such:

```
FROM <registry>:<port>/node:6.11
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

Once you build, the image will be downloaded from the private registry. Make sure that you are logged in to the registry before building using the `docker login` command.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the docker file. Pull the image from the private registry using `docker pull <registry>:<port>/node:6.11` and then force docker build to use this image by tagging it with only `node:6.11`

```
docker tag <registry>:<port>/node:6.11 node:6.11
```

Answer (score 2):

Before you build the Docker image you'll have to do `docker login` to your private repo. Then pulls - explicit or implicit through `FROM` will use that registry (and while I can't find any documentation to back that up, I suspect it also fallback to Docker Hub if it can't find the image there, but that may be dependent on the registry settings????)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have nodejs image in your local docker registry. 
If you want to pull the nodejs image from local docker registry:

- Make sure your docker daemon is pointing to local docker registry use `--insecure-registry <registry_address>:<port>` as mentioned here https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/
- Change Dockerfile to point to image in registry. `FROM <registry_address>:<port>/node:6.11` (actually this will be the complete name of your nodejs image in local docker registry)
- The registry credentials can be set using `docker login` command https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/ or you can manually set the credentials in `~/.docker/config.json` file.
- Now you can build the image, it should pull the base image from registry.